# YOLO anchor box

Tags: python, anchor, yolo

As I read the YOLO paper it says it makes anchor box with K-means.
However, when I see the code implementing this, it seems to fix anchor size as below.
I hope you describe what it exactly means or point out my misunderstanding with this.

Thanks, and regards

```
[yolo] 
mask = 6,7,8
***anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326***
```

Comment: We need more context than this.

Comment: Ctrl-F-ing for "means" in my [best guess](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf) for the paper you're talking about turns up no references to K-means.

Comment: Also, this isn't Python.

Comment: Sorry for my impolite question without context. The paper what I referenced is YOLO9000: Better, Faster, Stronger from below link. arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf From page 2, there is section with "Dimension Clusters." and it says YOLO 9000 makes anchor box with K means (not hand picked).

But from source implementing this, it makes anchor box from below configuration file with pre-fixed number. Please refer below.
(https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolo9000.cfg)

So, what I'm curious about is : why it should follow anchor box info without K-means.

Thanks again :)

Comment: The YOLO9000 config file doesn't look anything like what you've quoted in your post. The differences between the YOLO9000 and old config files look consistent with a switch to learned anchor priors. Maybe you were expecting the model to actually perform K-means at runtime?

Comment: If that exists, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor is like a default bounding box for a cell. It is composed of width and height for each anchor.

`anchors = anchor1_width, anchor1_height, anchor2_width, anchor2_height, ..., anchorN_width, anchorN_height`

You can generate your own anchors using this code if you are training yolov3
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/597#issuecomment-377370922

for yolov2 
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/scripts/gen_anchors.py

after you have generated your own anchors, replace default ones with yours in .cfg file

Answer (score 2):

As stated by other answer, the anchor boxes value in cfg file is only the initial value, later it will be **resized to the closest predicted object**. And you can generate your own anchor boxes using K-means as stated in other answer.

Here's the important thing, the initial value will be **resized**. Refer to this explanation by AlexeyAB. https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/568

> Anchors are initial sizes (width, height) some of which (the closest
>   to the object size) will be resized to the object size - using some
>   outputs from the neural network (final feature map):
>
> ```
> darknet/src/yolo_layer.c
>
> Lines 88 to 89 in 6f6e475
>
>  b.w = exp(x[index + 2*stride]) * biases[2*n]   / w;   
>  b.h = exp(x[index + 3*stride]) * biases[2*n+1] / h;
> ```
>
> `x[...]` - outputs of the neural network
>
> `biases[...]` - anchors
>
> b.w and b.h result width and height of bounded box that will be showed
>   on the result image
>
> Thus, the network should not predict the final size of the object, but
>   should only adjust the size of the nearest anchor to the size of the
>   object.
>
> In Yolo v3 anchors (width, height) - are sizes of objects on the image
>   that resized to the network size (width= and height= in the cfg-file).
>
> In Yolo v2 anchors (width, height) - are sizes of objects relative to
>   the final feature map (32 times smaller than in Yolo v3 for default
>   cfg-files).